# php looping solutions

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
<?php

$manifest_query = tep_db_query("select o.franchise_id, o.orders_id, o.customers_id,  o.delivery_name, o.delivery_street_address, o.delivery_city, o.delivery_postcode, o.delivery_state, o.customers_telephone, o.date_purchased from " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o, " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot where o.franchise_id = '" . (int)$franchise_id . "' and o.orders_id = ot.orders_id and ot.class = 'ot_total' and o.orders_status = '5'");

while ($manifest = tep_db_fetch_array($manifest_query))
{
    $products_query = tep_db_query("select orders_products_id, orders_id, products_id, products_model, products_name, products_quantity from " . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . " where orders_id = '" . (int)$manifest['orders_id'] . "'");
    $products = tep_db_fetch_array($products_query);
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td height="50" align="center"><?php echo $manifest['orders_id'] ;?></td>
    <td cellpadding="2"><?php echo $manifest['delivery_name'] .'<br> '. $manifest['delivery_street_address'] .'<br> '. $manifest['delivery_city'].'<br> '. $manifest['delivery_postcode'].'<br> '. $manifest['delivery_state'].'<br> '. $manifest['customers_telephone'] ;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $products['products_quantity'] . '&nbsp;x&nbsp;' . $products['products_name'] . '<br> ' . '&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$products['products_model'];?></td>
    <?php   
}
?>
```

The $products prints the products which are assigned to the order id in the 3rd column. But it only prints the first product which is assigned to the order, even if there are multiple products assigned to the order. Anyone know how to print all the products for the order_id?

Comment: try print_r($products); before the fist <tr> & check your while loop too.It isn't closed

Comment: at first sight i see that your while loop isn't closed.

Comment: sorry, forgot to close on my post

Comment: You need to put the closing brace in php tags <?php } ?>

Comment: verify and count the number of rows from your `$manifest_query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to nest a while loop. You only call the first row because you have only one loop.

```
<?php

 $manifest_query = tep_db_query("select o.franchise_id, o.orders_id, o.customers_id,  o.delivery_name, o.delivery_street_address, o.delivery_city, o.delivery_postcode, o.delivery_state, o.customers_telephone, o.date_purchased from " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o, " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot where o.franchise_id = '" . (int)$franchise_id . "' and o.orders_id = ot.orders_id and ot.class = 'ot_total' and o.orders_status = '5'");

while ($manifest = tep_db_fetch_array($manifest_query)){

$products_query = tep_db_query("select orders_products_id, orders_id, products_id, products_model, products_name, products_quantity from " . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . " where orders_id = '" . (int)$manifest['orders_id'] . "'");
    while($products = tep_db_fetch_array($products_query))


     ?>

      <tr>
      <td height="50" align="center"><?php echo $manifest['orders_id'] ;?></td>
      <td cellpadding="2"><?php echo $manifest['delivery_name'] .'<br> '. $manifest['delivery_street_address'] .'<br> '. $manifest['delivery_city'].'<br> '. $manifest['delivery_postcode'].'<br> '. $manifest['delivery_state'].'<br> '. $manifest['customers_telephone'] ;?></td>


      <td><?php echo $products['products_quantity'] . '&nbsp;x&nbsp;' . $products['products_name'] . '<br> ' . '&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$products['products_model'];?></td>



    <?php
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: this prints the order twice, one product ine one row, then repeats the row with next product in. Anyway of printing all the products to the order in one row?

Comment: Well, I've shown you how to solve your problem If I do the whole thing for you, you'll get lazy!

Answer (score 0):

Well in each while loop you make a new database query, so the old one is discarded, which means $product will only have the first entry. Make another while loop in the original while loop for $product.